# drupal: forum in menu

Tags: drupal, menu, drupal-modules, forum

I created a container with a couple of forums. How do I get it to appear in my menu?

I have book called "community", and I want the forum container to appear as a child of that book. I thought I could do it by using a view. I selected `node:type-->forum topic` as a filter, but I don't know what to enter in this field. It doesn't seem to be working.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have just a few containers, you can simply create the menu links by hand, make sure that you have the menu.module enabled.

You can also check out http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu, it allows to display taxonomies in the menu automatically and forums depend on taxonomy.